# Swift2: TKSubmitTransitionButton. How do i stop a button from transition/ animating when user login/ signup are incorrect

Tags: swift, animation, swift2, transition, uianimation

I have tried a number of times and the best i get is there would be an animation which never cancels or stop regardless of the command i use.

After following @Mattias example, i updated my code and looks something like this:

```
   // DESIGN ANIMATION... TKTRANSITIONSUBMITBUTTON
@IBOutlet weak var btnFromNib: TKTransitionSubmitButton!

@IBAction func onTapButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    btnFromNib.startLoadingAnimation()

        if let email = self.emailField.text where email != "", let password = self.passwordField.text where password != "" {

            DataService.ds.REF_BASE.authUser(email, password: password, withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in
                if error != nil {

                    self.btnFromNib.returnToOriginalState()
                    if error.code == STATUS_ACCOUNT_NONEXIST {

                        self.showErrorAlert("This User does not exist", msg: "Please Sign Up")
                    } else {

                    }

                } else {
                    self.btnFromNib.startFinishAnimation(1, completion: {
                        let myTabbarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myTabbarController") as! UITabBarController
                        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
                        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = myTabbarController

                        myTabbarController.transitioningDelegate = self
                    })

                }
            })
        }   
}
```

The button yet keeps spinning / animating without stopping. After checking the custom animation class the function inherits from :

```
     public func startLoadingAnimation() {
    self.cachedTitle = titleForState(.Normal)
    self.setTitle("", forState: .Normal)
    self.shrink()
    NSTimer.schedule(delay: shrinkDuration - 0.25) { timer in
        self.spiner.animation()
    }
}

public func startFinishAnimation(delay: NSTimeInterval, completion:(()->())?) {
    NSTimer.schedule(delay: delay) { timer in
        self.didEndFinishAnimation = completion
        self.expand()
        self.spiner.stopAnimation()
    }
}

public func animate(duration: NSTimeInterval, completion:(()->())?) {
    startLoadingAnimation()
    startFinishAnimation(duration, completion: completion)
}

public override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    let a = anim as! CABasicAnimation
    if a.keyPath == "transform.scale" {
        didEndFinishAnimation?()
        NSTimer.schedule(delay: 1) { timer in
            self.returnToOriginalState()
        }
    }
}

func returnToOriginalState() {
    self.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    self.setTitle(self.cachedTitle, forState: .Normal)
}
```

I noticed it had a      public overide func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished: Bool) to be the function to stop the animation. But when i use it, i get this error!

[image]

How do i rightfully get this to work? ...

Thanks in Advance

** UPDATED QUESTION **

Answer (score 1):

I checked the code of `TKTransitionSubmitButton` and there are public methods called `startLoadingAnimation()`, `returnToOriginalState()` and `startFinishAnimation()`.

I suggest:

```
Button tapped
startLoadingAnimation()
Check credentials
    If wrong/error: returnToOriginalState()
    If correct: startFinishAnimation()
```

Transition, from `TKTransitionSubmitButton` documentation:

```
btn.startFinishAnimation {
    //Your Transition
    let secondVC = SecondViewController()
    secondVC.transitioningDelegate = self
    self.presentViewController(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Edit: As far as I can see `.animate()` of the class calls both the start and finish animation, and that's why you can't cancel it.

**EDIT2** This one works as intended for me (however I'm not sure about the static cornerRadius)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var submitButton: TKTransitionSubmitButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    submitButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    submitButton.startLoadingAnimation()

    delay(2, closure: {

        self.checkCredentials()

    })


}

func checkCredentials()
{
    //FAKING WRONG CREDENTIALS
    let userAndPasswordCorrect = false

    if !userAndPasswordCorrect
    {
        submitButton.returnToOriginalState()
        //Alert or whatever
    }
}

//Faking network delay
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
}
```

Comment: would it be possible to write out the code for me please? ..  The     returnToOriginalState() isn't a public function and even when i make it, i get errors. Using your method is slightly confusing although it makes perfect sense

Comment: When i called the     returnToOriginalState() function, it didn't cancel the animation. Rather, it kept spinning. Seeing that animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished: Bool) does call the returnToOriginalState(). But i'm unable to write the code to get it to work.

Comment: I'll give it at shot!

Comment: Updated answer, worked for me. Good luck! (and the methods were all public to me, I didn't change anything in the button class)

Comment: I have updated the question. I tried your way a number of times with more tweaks but can't understand why it's not working. My guess is, if i'm successfully able to call the         public override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool), successfully, i'll get it to successfully stop the animation. Sorry for the bother. Thanks

Comment: Strange, it works fine for me. However I realised that it wouldn't work if I called the `returnToOriginalState()` too quick (no idea why). Try to copy the delay function from my answer and experiment.

Comment: is there a way to call the `func animationDidStop(CAAnimation, finished: true)`  as in calling it like so: `self.btnFromNib.animationDidStop(CAAnimation, finished: true)` ? although this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> ### I checked the code of TKTransitionSubmitButton.
>
> I resolve this issue. please try to stop animation under DispatchQueue.main.async and working well.

```
 'func apicallforLogin()  {
            let urlString = "http://"
            guard let requestUrl = URL(string:urlString) else { return }
            let request = URLRequest(url:requestUrl)
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
                (data, response, error) in
                if error == nil,let usableData = data {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.btnLogin.startFinishAnimation(0.1, completion: {
                            let HomeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
                            HomeVC.transitioningDelegate = self
                            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(HomeVC, animated: false)
                        })
                    }
                    print(usableData)
                }else{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.btnLogin.returnToOriginalState()
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you might have got the answer by now but just I would like to give my answer. You can just copy below code and everything will work fine. I have made the change and had created the pull request for this issue.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
open class TKTransitionSubmitButton : UIButton, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, CAAnimationDelegate {

    lazy var spiner: SpinerLayer! = {
        let s = SpinerLayer(frame: self.frame)
        return s
    }()

    @IBInspectable open var spinnerColor: UIColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            spiner.spinnerColor = spinnerColor
        }
    }

    open var didEndFinishAnimation : (()->())? = nil

    let springGoEase = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.45, -0.36, 0.44, 0.92)
    let shrinkCurve = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    let expandCurve = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.95, 0.02, 1, 0.05)
    let shrinkDuration: CFTimeInterval  = 0.1
    @IBInspectable open var normalCornerRadius:CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = normalCornerRadius
        }
    }

    var cachedTitle: String?
    var isAnimating = false

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setup()
    }

    public required init!(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        spiner.spinnerColor = spinnerColor
    }

    open func startLoadingAnimation() {
        self.isAnimating = true
        self.cachedTitle = title(for: UIControlState())
        self.setTitle("", for: UIControlState())
        self.layer.addSublayer(spiner)

        // Animate
        self.cornerRadius()
        self.shrink()
        _ = Timer.schedule(delay: self.shrinkDuration - 0.25) { timer in
            self.spiner.animation()
        }
    }

    open func startFinishAnimation(_ delay: TimeInterval,_ animation: CAMediaTimingFunction, completion:(()->())?) {
        self.isAnimating = true
        _ = Timer.schedule(delay: delay) { timer in
            self.didEndFinishAnimation = completion
            self.expand(animation)
            self.spiner.stopAnimation()
        }
    }

    open func animate(_ duration: TimeInterval,_ animation: CAMediaTimingFunction, completion:(()->())?) {
        startLoadingAnimation()
        startFinishAnimation(duration, animation, completion: completion)
    }

    open func setOriginalState() {
        self.returnToOriginalState()
        self.spiner.stopAnimation()
    }

    public func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        let a = anim as! CABasicAnimation
        if a.keyPath == "transform.scale" {
            didEndFinishAnimation?()
            _ = Timer.schedule(delay: 1) { timer in
                self.returnToOriginalState()
            }
        }
    }

    open func returnToOriginalState() {
        self.spiner.removeFromSuperlayer()
        self.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        self.setTitle(self.cachedTitle, for: UIControlState())
        self.spiner.stopAnimation()
        self.isAnimating = false
    }

    func cornerRadius() {
        let cornerRadiusAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "cornerRadius")
        // cornerRadiusAnim.fromValue = frame.width
        cornerRadiusAnim.toValue = frame.height/2
        cornerRadiusAnim.duration = shrinkDuration
        cornerRadiusAnim.timingFunction = shrinkCurve
        cornerRadiusAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        cornerRadiusAnim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        layer.add(cornerRadiusAnim, forKey: cornerRadiusAnim.keyPath)
    }

    func shrink() {
        let shrinkAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.width")
        shrinkAnim.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.1
        shrinkAnim.fromValue = frame.width
        shrinkAnim.toValue = frame.height
        shrinkAnim.duration = shrinkDuration
        shrinkAnim.timingFunction = shrinkCurve
        shrinkAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        shrinkAnim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        layer.add(shrinkAnim, forKey: shrinkAnim.keyPath)
    }

    func expand(_ animation: CAMediaTimingFunction) {
        let expandAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        expandAnim.fromValue = 1.0
        expandAnim.toValue = 26.0
        expandAnim.timingFunction = animation
        expandAnim.duration = 0.3
        expandAnim.delegate = self
        expandAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        expandAnim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        layer.add(expandAnim, forKey: expandAnim.keyPath)
    }

}
```